# How to select the column name with the biggest value as a new column element?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame named `a`, which can be shown as follow.

```
import pandas as pd 
a=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'label 0':[0.2,0.4,0.5],
'label 1':[0.3,0.2,0.1],'label 2':[0.5,0.4,0.4]})
```

`Input:`

```
    id  label 0  label 1  label 2
0   1     0.2     0.3     0.5
1   2     0.4     0.2     0.4
2   3     0.5     0.1     0.4
```

Each row contains the probability that each `id` belongs to three labels, where the three labels are `label 0`, `label 1`, `label 2`. I now want to use the `label` with the highest probability, the column name, as the predicted value of the `id`. If there are two labels with the highest probability, take one of them.

`Expected:`

```
    id   predict  
0   1    label 2     
1   2    label 0     
2   3    label 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for each row (i.e., axis=1):

```
a.drop('id', 1).idxmax(1)

#0    label 2
#1    label 0
#2    label 0
```

`concat` with the `id` column:

```
pd.concat([a.id, a.drop('id', 1).idxmax(1).rename('predict')], 1)

#   id  predict
#0   1  label 2
#1   2  label 0
#2   3  label 0
```

Comment: So this is when you're lurking about (-:

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

`a['prediction']=a[['label 0','label 1','label 2']].apply(max,axis=1)`

### Demo:

```
a['prediction']=a[['label 0','label 1','label 2']].apply(max,axis=1)
a=a.drop(['label 0','label 1','label 2'],1)
print(a)
```

#### Output:

```
    id  prediction
0   1         0.5
1   2         0.4
2   3         0.5
```